# Represent sets as binary numbers: how is this technique called?

Tags: terminology, boolean-algebra, binary

I've been using a technique that consists in representing sets as binary numbers. This is, given a vocabulary $v = \{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$ and a set $s = \{s_1, s_2, ..., s_m\}$ where $s_i \in v$, then the set $s$ can be represented as a binary number $b_s$ of length $n$ where

$$b_s[i] = 
\begin{cases}
1 \; \text{if} \; v[i] \in s \\
0 \; \text{if} \; v[i] \notin s \\
\end{cases}
$$

For example, if $v = \{a, b, c\}$ and $s = \{a, b\}$ then $b_s = 011$. And if $t=\{b, c\}$ then $b_t = 110$.

My question is how is this technique called. I've googled "represent a set as a binary number" and multiple variants, but nothing appears. Also, is this technique something standard?

Comment: I have never seen a specific name attached to this technique.  I have never really studied Set Theory.  Given that, the technique that you describe is the first thing that I thought of when I read your question's title.

Comment: It's just a type of encoding. You could call it a "binary encoding" but that doesn't convey any more information than "encoding" in this case: To give it a more precise name we would need to know more about how you chose which binary number represents which element in the set? Was there a methodology?

Comment: @John_Krampf I could be mistaken.  I would infer from the posting that $v$ is any set with a finite number (i.e. $n$) of elements, and that the individual elements were randomly assigned indices from $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, sampling from $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ without replacement.

Comment: @user2661923 you're right. Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: If they're randomly assigned then there is no special name. You can call it a "randomly assigned binary encoding". Alternatives that aren't randomly assigned are things like shannon encoding, prefix free binary encoding, one-hot encoding, and others.

Comment: But/and what kind of "random assignment" are you using? In an algorithmic context, the assignment obviously has to be explicitly specified in some fashion...

Comment: Why are there lots of comments involving the word "random" that doesn't appear in the question? The standard terminology for this concept in computer science is "bitmap" and the approach is standard in mathematics and in computing.

Comment: @RobArthan, one point is that a set is not truly "ordered", by nature, which opens possibilities for ambiguity in terms of giving a list _or_ set of yes-no's about whether elements are included in the subset... akin, in my mind, to giving the set of values of a function, without telling which inputs give which outputs. Maybe I'm just not hip to relevant CompSci conventions here.

Comment: @paulgarrett: the question has an enumeration of the set as a given (the function $i \mapsto v_i$). I don't see the relevance of your comment.

Comment: @RobArthan, ah, I guess I didn't understand that there was a given enumeration. I was reading it as "given a set, construct an enumeration, and ..."

Comment: @RobArthan The question we're asking OP is how that enumeration is constructed. And yes if you want to be pedantic by random we mean arbitrary.

Comment: @John_Krampf: the question gives the enumeration and it is irrelevant how that enumeration was constructed.

Comment: @RobArthan The construction of the enumeration determines the the construction of the encoding, which is what it gives its name. Naming it without knowing the construction is conveys as much information as "mathematical object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a set implemented using a [bit array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array).

And it is a “standard” technique. The first time I encountered it was in Turbo Pascal, which used it to implement its `set` types.

An advantage of this representation is that set operations can easily and efficiently be implemented using bitwise operators: `x & y` for intersection, `x | y` for union, `x ^ y` for symmetric difference, or `x & ~y` for difference.

The main disadvantage is that it can't be used for sets of types with large numbers of possible values.  (If `int` is 32 bits, then each `set<int>` would be $2^{32}$ bits = 512 megabytes.)  For this reason, Turbo Pascal only allowed sets to contain values between 0 and 255, thus limiting the maximum size of a `set` object to a more practical 256 bits = 32 bytes.